# In Didache 16, is the author teaching a perfectionism at odds with Catholicism and Protestantism?

Tags: perfection, didache

> ...**Chapter 16. Watchfulness; the Coming of the Lord**. Watch for your life's sake. Let not your lamps be quenched, nor your loins unloosed; but be ready, for you know not the hour in which our Lord will come. But come together often, seeking the things which are befitting to your souls: **for the whole time of your faith will not profit you, if you are not made perfect in the last time...**

Is that the Catholic view?

The Protestant view?

Any other major sect's view?

Comment: Nice to see you here again, and I trust you are well.  I would respectfully ask who is the authour of the Didache?  I think the verse you have quoted has a basis in the New Testament.   https://www.earlychristianwritings.com/text/didache-roberts.html

Comment: Hi Lesley and thank you for your kind welcome. 

The Didache, as usual, is anonymous.

Comment: Well, if this question remains in the Christianity section, you might get some answers from Catholics and Protestants, which would be interesting. Signing off for tonight but will check this question out tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The author is asserting the Catholic doctrine on salvation which teaches that a man must be in a state of grace, that is friendship with God, at the moment of his death to enter Heaven.**

Due to the sin of Adam we have lost the inheritance of sanctifying grace because he squandered it. Thus every man is born in a state of damnation and he remains so until he receives faith through baptism as indicated in *John 3:36*

> “He who believes in the Son has eternal life, and he who disobeys the Son shall not see life but the wrath of God abides on him.”

Catholics can lose the state of grace by severing themselves from God by committing a mortal sin, which is a deliberate sin concerning grave matter, such as sins of the flesh, idolatry, heresy, schism, etc.

Even cherishing a single sinful thought is enough to merit Hell.

St. Alphonsus, *[On the Number of Sins Beyond Which God Pardons No More](https://endtimes.video/death-and-the-journey-into-hell/)*:

> St. Gregory the Great relates that a child, five years old, who had
> arrived at the use of reason, was seized by a Devil for having uttered
> a blasphemy, and carried in the Hell. Another boy of eight died after his first sin, and was lost forever.  The Holy Mother of God revealed to that great Servant of God, Benedicta of Florence, that a girl of twelve was damned after her first sin.

Because sin is an offense against God's infinite majesty, no punishment is severe enough, however, He mercifully offers us the graces and opportunities to repent.

Most Protestants reject this teaching and believe God forensically justifies, that is "covers" the sins of the person but does not erase them. This is problematic since God as perfect good cannot dwell with evil but he destroys it by his presence. As we see from *2 Samuel 6:6-7*:

> And when they came to the floor of Nachon, Oza put forth his hand to
> the ark of God, and took hold of it: because the oxen kicked and made
> it lean aside. And the indignation of the Lord was enkindled
> against Oza, and he struck him for his rashness: and he died there
> before the ark of God.

Comment: Hi Glorius. You wrote "receives faith through baptism;" did you mean to write "receives grace through baptism"?

Comment: @Ruminator No, I mean't faith, although grace is also correct. Baptism is of course the most necessary grace without which one is certainly lost (cf. John 3:5).
Pope Clement VI, Super quibusdam: "...all those who in baptism have received the same Catholic faith..."
Catechism of Trent, on the  “Our Father,” p. 510: "...for all have been regenerated by the same Spirit through the same Sacrament of faith..."
One also receives the Blood of Redemption, Spirit of Sanctification, and first justification with baptism.
This is the clear teaching of Scripture and Tradition.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the clarification.